# Не происходит внедрение зависимостей через Spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, зависимости

Всем привет! Изучаю java, в качестве практики пишу pet проект.
Для связи с базой данных в проекте использую такой репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface MeetingRepository extends CrudRepository<Meeting, Long> {
    boolean existsByPassphrase(String passphrase);
}
```

Однако, при использовании его в классе:

```
@Component
public class newMeeting implements ActionInterface {

    @Autowired
    MeetingRepository meetingRepository;
    @Autowired
    Meeting meeting;

    @Override
    public Update isPassphraseOk(Update update) {
        String passphrase = update.getMessage();
        String chatId = update.getChatID().toString();

        //вызов meetingRepository
        if (meetingRepository.existsByPassphrase(passphrase)) {
            String text = "Это название уже занято, попробуйте ввести другое название";
            update.setMessage(text);
            return update;
        } else {
            meeting.setPassphrase(passphrase);
            String text = "Это название уже занято, попробуйте ввести другое название";
            update.setMessage(text);
            return update;
        }
    }
}
```

получаю

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Cannot invoke "org.example.MeetingRepository.existsByPassphrase(String)" 
because "this.meetingRepository" is null
```

Подскажите, почему не происходит внедрение зависимостей, хотя репозиторий помечен @Repository, поле помечено как @Autowired и Intrllij определяет правильно их использование?

[image]

UPD github проекта
https://github.com/gleb-esin/meetingRepository_is_not_working

Comment: возможно бин репозитория не был просканирован. нужно понимать, какая структура пакетов и где находится @SpringBootApplication класс

Comment: https://github.com/gleb-esin/meetingRepository_is_not_working

Comment: есть 2 варианта: оставить класс Main там же, а остальные опустить на уровень ниже (т.е. создать вложенный пакет/пакеты). Либо добавить в Main аннотацию @ComponentScan("org.example")

Comment: а, забыл. для репозиториев есть ещё аннотация @EnableJpaRepositories с таким же параметром. тоже в Main добавить.

Comment: Попробовал всё - по-прежнему получаю Cannot invoke "org.example.MeetingRepository.existsByPassphrase(String)" 
Ваш фикс закоммитил, посмотрите, пожалуйчта, правильно я ли Вас понял.

Comment: @EnableJpaRepositories("org.example.service") - это должно быть в Main

Comment: И это не помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в совершенно другом месте:

```
 private final Map<String, ActionInterface> actions = Map.of(
            "/new", new newMeeting());
```

newMeeting это бин, соответственно при создании этого класса через new, все внедряемые зависимости будут null. В том числе и зависимость на репозиторий.
Как это решить:

1. Расширить интерфейс `ActionInterface` методом, который возвращает стринговый ключ для соответствующего экшина
2. Реализовать этот метод в пока единственной реализации этого интерфейса
3. Заинжектить в бин TelegramBot все бины с типом ActionInterface -
   `@Autowired  private List<ActionInterface> actionBeans;`
4. Создать метод, который в зависимости от значения ключа выбирает нужный бин

   private ActionInterface resolveAction(String key) {

   ```
        for (var a : actionBeans) {
            if (a.getActionKey().equals(key)) {
                return a;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
   ```
5. заменить все вызовы `actions.get(key)` на `resolveAction(key)`